# Input with cin is not working in switch case

Tags: c++, switch-statement, cin

I am creating a program which asks user for reply and how many time you want to print reply and display it. I have used a while loop and switch case in the program.
But when I store input in variable `a` with help of `std::cin`, the same input is not received by switch case. Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a;
int input;
int i=1;
void display()
{
    cout << "Select a choice for reply" << endl;
    cout << "1.Thank You" << endl;
    cout << "2.Welcome" << endl;
    cout << "3.Okay" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    display();
    cout << "Enter Choice" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    input='a';
    switch (input)
    {
        case '1': {
            int x;
            cout << "Enter no. of times  you want to print reply line" << endl;
            cin >> x;
            while (i <= x)
            {
                cout << "Thank you" << endl;
            }

            break;
        }
        case '2': {
            int x;
            cout << "Enter no. of times  you want to print line" << endl;
            cin >> x;
            while (i <= x)
            {
                cout << "Welcome" << endl;
            }

            break;
        }
        case '3': {
            int x;
            cout << "Enter no. of times  you want to print line" << endl;
            cin >> x;
            while (i <= x)
            {
                cout << "okay" << endl;
            }

            break;
        }
        default: {
            cout << "wrong choice" << endl;
        }

        cout << "Thank you for replying" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `case '1'` - um. little chance that is going to work for you. I don't suppose you tried `case 1` (i.e., don't use character literals). And since neither `i` nor `x` are changed in your  ensuing `while` loops, it is destined to spin to infinity, even if you fix the first problem. I *strongly* suggest a [good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Please format your code correctly, like the samples in your C++ textbook.

Comment: you declared `input` as `integer` then assigned `input='a'`. after that you put `switch(input)`.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: I think you're confusing digits (`'9'`)  with numbers (`9`).

Answer (score 3):

The core Problem is:

```
input = 'a'
```

And:

```
case '1':
```

What you probably want is:

```
input = a

case 1:
```

After all the Compiler should have thrown a warning.
But why copy the value after all?
Just do

```
switch(a)
```

Actually, there are many problems with your code, but I'll let other people elaborate this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `input='a';`, input value will be 97, it is the same if you write `input = (int)'a';`

Why are you declare 'a' variable? Just use input 
    `cin >> input;`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a;
int input;
int i=1;
void display()
{
    cout<<"Select a choice for reply"<<endl;
    cout<<"1.Thank You"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Welcome"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Okay"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    display();
    cout<<"Enter Choice"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    input=a;
    switch(input)
    {
        case 1 :
        {
            int x;
            cout<<"Enter no. of times  you want to print reply 
            line<<endl;
            cin>>x;
            while(i<=x)
            {
                cout<<"Thank you"<<endl;
                x--;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2 :
        {
            int x;
            cout<<"Enter no. of times  you want to print line" <<endl;
            cin>>x;
            while(i<=x)
            {
                cout<<"Welcome"<<endl;
                x--;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3 :
        {
            int x;
            cout<<"Enter no. of times  you want to print line"<<endl;
            cin>>x;
            while(i<=x)
            {
                cout<<"okay"<<endl;
                x--;
            }
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout<<"wrong choice"<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"Thank you for replying"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is input='a';, input value will be 97, it is the same if you write input = (int)'a';Also there was no need to take two different variables that is a and input,one was sufficient.But since you declared and used these two variables i didn't removed that from your program.When you write case st. in switch then always remember syntax for integer is (case 1 :)where 1 can be replaced by any number you providing as a choice and syntax for character (case 'a':).Also in while loop you forgot to gave terminating condition(x--;).

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems in your code:

 1) You try to give an integer an char: `input = 'a';` 
 To do it right you should use the variable directly: `input = a;` (without ') 
2) In your switch case you compare with '1', '2' (type char) but `input` is of type integer. Try this: 
 `case 1:` and `case 2:`(without ') 
3) You dont increment/decrement i or x in your while loops, they will never stop. Try something like: `i++` or `x--` somewhere in your loops. 
Some remarks:

1) You can use switch case without curly brackets ({ }):

```
int a = 0;
cin >> 1;
switch(a)
{
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        int tmp = 0;
        cout<<"tmp: "<<tmp<<endl;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

2) Try to avoid global variables, they are in most cases not necessary and bad practice. 
3) You dont need your variable `a`, you can use `input` directly, like:

```
cout << "Enter Choice" << endl;
cin >> input;
switch (input)
```

4) Last but not least I recommend you to read some good c++ books, it is realy worth it. ([Good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list))